# Objective C memory leaking

Tags: objective-c, memory, memory-leaks, outlet, narc

I'm creating one Cocoa application for myself and I found a problem. I have two NSTextFields and they're connected to each other as nextKeyViews. When I run this app with memory leaks detection tool and tab through those 2 textboxes for a while, enter some text etc., I start to leak memory. It shows me that the AppKit library is responsible, the leaked objects are NSCFStrings and the responsible frames are `[NSEvent charactersIgnoringModifiers]` and `[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:]`. I know this is quite a brief and incomplete description, but does anyone have any ideas what could be the problem?

Also, I don't use GC, so I `release` my instance variables in the controllers `dealloc`. What about the outlets? Since `IBOutlet` is just a mark for Interface Builder and doesn't actually mean anything, should I `release` them too?

Answer (score 1):

> What about the outlets? Since IBOutlet is just a mark for Interface Builder and doesn't actually mean anything, should I release them too?

Your declaration of the `IBOutlet` tells you how to manage it... If you declare it as `retained` and then `@synthesize` it, the process of loading the nib will `retain` the outlet. Therefore you must `release` it.

[Andiih](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107565/andiih) [coined the mnemonic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865185/do-you-need-to-release-parameters-of-methods-at-the-end-of-them-in-objective-c) [NARC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/narc)

> NARC: "New Alloc Retain Copy". If you
>   are not doing any of those things, you
>   don't need to release.

The corollary is also true.. if you do any of those, you are responsible for releasing the object at the appropriate time.