# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in viewDidLoad of FlipsideViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm trying to display some data on the flip side view of a utility template application but the application aborts at the end of viewDidLoad method. I'm very new to iOS and could do with a bit of guidance.

```
[super viewDidLoad];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor viewFlipsideBackgroundColor];
NSString *thePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SavedData"ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *tempRootDictionary;
NSMutableArray *tempMutableArray;
if (thePath && (tempRootDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:thePath])) {
    NSArray *keys = [tempRootDictionary allKeys];
    int keysCount = [keys count];
    tempMutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:keysCount];
    for (int i=0; i<keysCount; i++) {
        NSDictionary *dictionary = [tempRootDictionary objectForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:i]];
        MyModelObject *aModelObject = [[MyModelObject alloc] init];
        [aModelObject setName:[dictionary objectForKey:@"name"]];
        [aModelObject setContext:[dictionary objectForKey:@"context"]];
        [aModelObject setUsername:[dictionary objectForKey:@"username"]];
        [aModelObject setPassword:[dictionary objectForKey:@"password"]];
        [tempMutableArray addObject:aModelObject];
        [aModelObject release];
        [dictionary release];
    }
} else {
    return;
}
```

Help would be really appreciated,
Many thanks...

Comment: Anything suspicious in `MyModelObject`?

Comment: Have you narrowed it down to the exact line that causes the error?  At least the `[dictionary release];` line is wrong and should be removed.  You didn't alloc `dictionary` so don't release it.

Answer (score 1):

The only obvious problem I see in the code posted is this:

```
[dictionary release];
```

On the line that you set dictionary, you are only getting a reference to the object in tempRootDictionary and not a new alloc'd instance of it.  So don't release it.  Remove that line.

Comment: Could you please also guide me to a resource where i can learn objective-c on the whole (whether i develop for macOS or iOS) and especially the basics like this one?

Comment: See Apple's [Introduction To The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html) and the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html).

Comment: [This SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865185/do-you-need-to-release-parameters-of-methods-at-the-end-of-them-in-objective-c) by @Andiih also gives a nice acronym to remember the memory management rules by.