# Memory leak in using NSDictionary of NSDictionaries

Tags: iphone, objective-c, debugging, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am trying to parse XML. I basically have an NSMutableDictionary (say root) the elements of which are other dictionaries (say branch_1, branch_2, branch_3, etc).

While parsing XML, for each branch, I'm creating an NSMutableDictionary and adding elements to it this way:

```
if ([elementName compare:@"branch_1"] == NSOrderedSame) 
{
    [root setObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] forKey:@"branch_1"]; //Creating a new NSMutableDictionary            
} 

//Adding elements to the newly created NSMutabeDictionary 

if ([elementName compare:@"element_1"] == NSOrderedSame) 
{
   [[root objectForKey:@"branch_1"] setObject:someObject forKey:@"element_1"];                                      
} 

if ([elementName compare:@"element_2"] == NSOrderedSame) 
{
   [[root objectForKey:@"branch_1"] setObject:someObject forKey:@"element_2"];                                      
}
```

I then finally release my root dictionary in the dealloc method. However the analyze tool in Xcode shows a leak in the line where I've created new dictionaries for branch_1 etc.

I'm guessing I should release the branch dictionaries before I release the root dictionary. However shouldn't the contents of the root dictionary be freed on releasing the root itself ?

Please let me know how I can fix this leak. Any help will be appreciated !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, that you don't release the references to the newly created dictionary. In

```
[root setObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] forKey:@"branch_1"];
```

you create a new dictionary by virtue of

```
[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]
```

Your root dictionary will `retain` that value. The original reference, [for which you are responsible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865185/do-you-need-to-release-parameters-of-methods-at-the-end-of-them-in-objective-c/2865194#2865194) because you used `alloc` to obtain it, is leaked here. So, try

```
[[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease]
```

instead.

**Edit** Another way to achieve the desired behaviour would be to use one of the convenience constructor methods defined by class `NSMutableDictionary`:

```
[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]
```

The object will be kept alive as long as *someone* has a (properly `retain`ed) reference to it. In this case, your root dictionary will hold onto the newly created child dictionary (`setObject:forKey:` sends the `retain` message to the values).

Comment: …or `[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]`.

Comment: @zoul: ... which would actually be shorter. Thanks. Will edit my answer.

Comment: On doing this, will the objects not be released prematurely? I want the objects (represented by "someObject" in my code) to to stick around throughout the duration of the application.